# Exclude zero terms from being counted for `combn` in a function in r

Tags: r, function, dataframe, matrix, combinations

I want to run the following function

```
Proposed <- function(N_b,N_l,m,A,x.sqr,e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5,K_g,a,b,c,d) {
  e <- data.frame(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5,N_l)
  CSi <- if (A > 0) m * ((N_l/N_b) * ((a*K_g)^b) + 
            ((A * (apply(e,1,function(v) max(combn(v[1:ncol(e)],v["N_l"],sum)))))
             / x.sqr) * ((c*K_g)^d)) 
  else ((N_l/N_b) * ((a*K_g)^b) + 
            ((A * (apply(e,1,function(v) min(combn(v[1:ncol(e)],v["N_l"],sum)))))
             / x.sqr) * ((c*K_g)^d))
  return(CSi)
}
```

with sample dataframe

```
dput(DATA1)
structure(list(N_l = c(2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3), N_b = c(5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), m = c(1, 0.65, 1, 0.65, 1.2, 1, 1.2, 0.85), 
A = c(-12, -12, -15, -15, -9, -9, -9, -9), x.sqr = c(1440, 
1440, 2250, 2250, 810, 810, 810, 810), e_1 = c(21.8, 21.8, 
29, 29, 14.6, 14.6, 14.6, 14.6), e_2 = c(9.8, 9.8, 17, 17, 
2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6), e_3 = c(-2.2, -2.2, 5, 5, -9.4, -9.4, 
-9.4, -9.4), e_4 = c(-14.2, -14.2, -7, -7, 0, 0, 0, 0), e_5 = c(0, 
0, -19, -19, 0, 0, 0, 0), K_g = c(6340598.65753794, 6340598.65753794, 
6429472.98493414, 6429472.98493414, 6296482.86883766, 6296482.86883766, 
8140521.8248051, 8140521.8248051)), row.names = c(20L, 40L, 
60L, 80L, 100L, 120L, 140L, 160L), class = "data.frame")
```

Using another function for nonlinear regression:

```
library(minpack.lm)

Girder1_nlsLM <- nlsLM(CSi ~ Proposed(N_b,N_l,m,A,x.sqr,e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5,K_g,a,b,c,d), 
             data = DATA1, 
             start = c(a = 0.01, b = 0.01, c = 0.01, d = 0.01))
```

This code runs fine as it is. But as you can see in the sample dataframe DATA1, some of the terms in e columns (e)1, e_2, e_3, etc...) are zero. I was to exclude these terms from the main function (Proposed) so I add:

```
Proposed <- function(N_b,N_l,m,A,x.sqr,e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5,K_g,a,b,c,d) {
  e <- data.frame(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5,N_l)
  ee <- e[e != 0]
  CSi <- if (A > 0) m * ((N_l/N_b) * ((a*K_g)^b) + 
            ((A * (apply(ee,1,function(v) max(combn(v[1:ncol(ee)],v["N_l"],sum)))))
             / x.sqr) * ((c*K_g)^d)) 
  else ((N_l/N_b) * ((a*K_g)^b) + 
            ((A * (apply(ee,1,function(v) min(combn(v[1:ncol(ee)],v["N_l"],sum)))))
             / x.sqr) * ((c*K_g)^d))
  return(CSi)
}
```

But when I use `ee` instead of `e` I get the error:

```
Error in apply(ee, 1, function(v) min(combn(v[1:ncol(ee)], v["N_l"], sum))) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

I don't know how to remove the zero terms for each row without getting this error.

Comment: `e[e != 0]` is not a good way to subset a data frame - the result is just a vector, not a data frame. Maybe you want `e[rowSums(e == 0) == 0, ]`, which would omit rows where there are any 0s.

Comment: Thank you @GregorThomas, Solved the problem!